# raise RestClient::ServerBrokeConnection rails error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, rest-client

when My request return huge json as a result [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) return error:

```
raise RestClient::ServerBrokeConnection
```

but smaller json result works well

Comment: Did you consider https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#streaming-responses

Comment: @ChenKinnrot no, let me check